# Runtime.getRuntime().exec(fileupload) is showing error(C# Selenium Webdriver)

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, autoit

I would like to write the code for uploading file using Autoit in Selenium Webdriver(C#). I have installed Autoit. Create the exe file where I have mentioned the file location which I want to upload.

But when I write :

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(fileupload);
```

It shows me the following error:

```
object doest not contain a definition for "getRuntime" and no extension method getRuntime.
```

Am I missing something? Can anyone help?

Comment: please share autoIT script .

Comment: ControlFocus("Open","","Edit1")
ControlSetText("Open","","Edit1","C:\Users\Shahabuddin\Desktop\Rumana\IndustryConnect\Implemented_Code\info.txt")
ControlClick("Open","","Edit1")

Comment: info.txt is present at specified location.

Comment: autoIT script seems fine to me !

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation **Runtime.getRuntime().exec()** method takes the absolute path of the executable along with the extension i.e. `.exe`. So you need to modify your code as follows :

- *C# Binding Art* :

  ```
  Runtime.getRuntime().exec(@"C:\\path\\to\\AutoIT\\fileupload.exe");
  ```
- *Java Binding Art* :

  ```
  Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\path\\to\\AutoIT\\fileupload.exe");
  ```